# Which groovy does grails use when run from the command line

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-tool-suite

*I did not install Groovy.*
I have installed **Grails** and I am able to run my app from the command line!

**Where is it getting a Groovy compiler?**

**N.B** I have STS that has its own Groovy compiler.

Are they sharing the STS's Groovy compiler? If that is so, is it also possible to point STS to a Groovy compiler installed by **gvm** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails comes with the version of Groovy that it's compatible with, like all of the other dependencies (e.g. the various Spring jars, Hibernate jars, commons-lang, etc.) They're all in the `$GRAILS_HOME/lib` directory (the Grails jars and their source and javadoc jars are in the `$GRAILS_HOME/dist` directory).

You only need to install Groovy if you want to run Groovy scripts and programs independently from Grails apps.

STS and other IDEs use their own Groovy compiler, but Grails has no integrations with any IDEs other than creating project files.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy is bundled with Grails. If the location where Grails is installed is given by `$GRAILS_HOME`, you'll find the bundled Groovy at `lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars`.